# activate extensions without accessing backend in TYPO3 6.2

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I just upgraded my TYPO3 4.5 to 6.2 lts. After I had to deactivate an extension , more specifically "dam" because of its incompatibility, and I had to deactivate some other dam extensions because they depend on "dam". Now when I try to access the backend , I get some fatal errors related to require once. I just want to reactivate those extensions I just deactivated without Backend , maybe via Install Tool if it's possible. Do you know a trick to achieve this ? is it possible ? if no, how can I go back to the previous version knowing I didn't back it up

Comment: In typo3 6.2 install tool there is an option to check form incompatible extension. If there are any , then you can uninstall through this .

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file PackageStates.php which is inside of the typo3conf folder.

```
'tt_guest' => 
array (
  'state' => 'inactive',
  'packagePath' => 'typo3/ext/tt_guest/',
  'classesPath' => 'Classes/',
  'suggestions' => 
  array (
  ),
),
```

You can set the state to 'active' or to 'inactive'. You can add additional entries or remove entries from the PHP array which is returned in this file. This will be nearly the same as installing and deinstalling an extension. You only need to do the DB checks in the Install Tool after you have activated an extension. Otherwise the database tables needed by an extension might not be in the needed format.